# Python PostGIS script add new field on polygons layers

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql

I have create a Python script where use PostGIS queries to automate some intersection tasks using PostGIS database.

In my database I have polygons, points and lines.

Here's​ a snippet of my script :

```
 try:
        if str(geomtype) == 'point':
            geomtype = 1
        elif str(geomtype) == 'linestring':
            geomtype = 2
        elif str(geomtype) == 'polygon':
            geomtype = 3
        else:
            raise TypeError()
    sql = "\nDROP TABLE IF EXISTS {0}.{1};\nCREATE TABLE {0}.{1} AS (SELECT {4},\n(st_dump(ST_CollectionExtract(st_intersection(dbgis.{2}.shape,dbgis.{3}.shape)::GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY,2345),{5}))).geom AS shape\nFROM  dbgis.{2}, dbgis.{3} WHERE st_intersects(dbgis.{2}.shape,dbgis.{3}.shape) AND {5}=3);\nCREATE INDEX idx_{2}_{3}_{6} ON {0}.{1} USING GIST (shape);\nALTER TABLE {0}.{1} ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;\nALTER TABLE {0}.{1} ADD COLUMN my_area double precision;\nUPDATE {0}.{1} SET my_area = ST_AREA(shape::GEOMETRY);\nALTER TABLE {0}.{1} ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);\nSELECT pop_g_col('{0}.{1}'::REGCLASS);\nGRANT ALL ON {0}.{1} TO GROUP u_cl;\nGRANT ALL ON {0}.{1} TO GROUP my_user;\n-- VACUUM ANALYZE {0}.{1};\n".format(schema, table, tablea, tableb, selects, geomtype, id_gen())
    return sql
```

This PostGIS SQL query works​ nice, but I need the new field where I want to add `my_area` to create only for polygons layers.

That code create for all layers (lines, points, polygons) that field `my_area` if layer is point or line then take value 0 I don't like that I don't need it.

How to change this code to create `my_area` only in polygons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn´t able to test this, but you should be able to use `CASE WHEN THEN END` in your initial `SELECT` to add and populate `my_area` if `geomtype = 3`, e.g. something along the lines of this:

```
   CREATE TABLE {0}.{1} AS
     (SELECT subquery.*,
             CASE {3} WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT ST_Area(shape::GEOMETRY))
             END AS my_area
      FROM  (SELECT {4},
                    (st_dump(ST_CollectionExtract(st_intersection(dbgis.{2}.shape,dbgis.{3}.shape)::GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY, 2345), {5}))).geom AS shape
             FROM  dbgis.{2}, dbgis.{3}
             WHERE st_intersects(dbgis.{2}.shape, dbgis.{3}.shape)
               AND {5} = 3) AS subquery);
```

I wrote this out of my head and might have overseen something but I think, in general, this structure should get you going.

You could, of course, do the conditional selection within your python code, e.g. write two sql strings according to your needs and let your `if ... elif ...` statement return the one you need based on `geomtype`.

EDIT:

Important: I had to alter the query above slightly to make it work!

And this would be your `sql` string, use it as in your code above:

```
sql = "\nDROP TABLE IF EXISTS {0}.{1};\nCREATE TABLE {0}.{1} AS (SELECT subquery.*, CASE {3} WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT ST_Area(shape::GEOMETRY)) END AS my_area FROM (SELECT {4}, (st_dump(ST_CollectionExtract(st_intersection(dbgis.{2}.shape,dbgis.{3}.shape)::GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY, 2345), {5}))).geom AS shape FROM dbgis.{2}, dbgis.{3} WHERE st_intersects(dbgis.{2}.shape, dbgis.{3}.shape) AND {5} = 3) AS subquery);\nCREATE INDEX idx_{2}_{3}_{6} ON {0}.{1} USING GIST (shape);\nALTER TABLE {0}.{1} ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;\nALTER TABLE {0}.{1} ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);\nSELECT pop_g_col('{0}.{1}'::REGCLASS);\nGRANT ALL ON {0}.{1} TO GROUP u_cl;\nGRANT ALL ON {0}.{1} TO GROUP my_user;\n-- VACUUM ANALYZE {0}.{1};\n".format(schema, table, tablea, tableb, selects, geomtype, id_gen())
```

If this query does not work, please post your error message.

Comment: @ThingumaBobthat look great but  can you show me an example with my code in sql where I use ?I talk that because I am very new and confused

Comment: @jessiejes do you still need help? look closely, I just altered the table creation part in your code: in 'sql', replace that first part with above query, and near the end of your 'sql' remove both the part where you add the column 'my_area' and where you set it to st_area.

Comment: yes maybe more because firs time to use POSTGIS and i am more confused because i use and python....show me if you can complete example with my code to can test it?...thnx you btw you are very good i know undestard where i need but i ant to execute yet

Comment: @jessiejes okay I edited my answer.

Comment: realy thnx you i will test it now and i ping you if tesi is success or not thnx you again

Comment: @jessiejes one more thing, don't accept an answer until all questions are solved, so that others might still be intetested in helping

Comment: finaly don't work my friend I have error at `CASE {3} WHEN 3 THEN` any idea why ?

Comment: @jessiejes what error message do you get? try replacing it with `CASE WHEN {3} = 3 THEN`

Comment: @jessiejess ah wait, try `{5}` instead of `{3}` first!

Comment: that is the first to try and nothing again